# Can't make updates in some product and theme option wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, .htaccess, woocommerce

i can't make updates in some product or exemple those published in 2020-10  and i can't make update theme option
**i did all upgrades, i checked php version , i generate a new .htaccess file but always same error
**

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access this resource.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the following things:

1. That your file permissions are set correctly
2. That there isn't any php that would prevent you from carrying out these actions such as someone having added code disabling the actions or relevant admin pages in functions.php
3. Check for any other additional htaccess files in the wp_content / themes / plugin folders that might be causing it
4. Check your WP user is admin and that there isn't a plugin that is changing your users permissions etc.